# Setting Property in Apache Camel in XML

Tags: java, apache-camel, blueprint-osgi

I'm new to apache camel. Need help on the below.

I have 2 routes. From route A I'm sending only 1 property to another route using a method call. like

```
        <camel:route id="processMessageRoute">
        <camel:from uri="direct:processMessageRoute" /> 

        <camel:setProperty propertyName="MessageMap">
            <camel:method bean="ServiceBean" method="initMessageMap" />
        </camel:setProperty>

        <camel:setProperty propertyName="MessageBelongerMap">
            <camel:method bean="ServiceBean" method="initMessageBelongerMap" />
        </camel:setProperty>

    <camel:to uri="bean:ServiceBean?method=saveMessageData(${property.MessageBelongerMap})" />
```

Inside ServiceBean class, I have

```
public boolean saveMessageData(Map<String, Object> MessageBelongerMap) {

    producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:processMessage", MessageBelongerMap);

    return true;
```

Now my problem is I need to pass both the properties MessageMap, MessageBelongerMap but I don't see any option here. Need help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a 2nd parameter in your bean method

```
public boolean saveMessageData(Map<String, Object> MessageBelongerMap,
                               Map<String, Object> MessageMap) {
```

And then bind to the 2nd parameter from Camel

```
<camel:to uri="bean:ServiceBean?method=saveMessageData(${property.MessageBelongerMap}, ${property.MessageMap})" />
```

Comment: Sorry I was able to get till here but I don't understand how to pass 2 properties from bean to another route. In 
    producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:processMessage", MessageBelongerMap);

I can pass only one object as an argument to another route.

Comment: There is a requestBodyAndMap where the map is headers. If you need exchange properties then you need to use request which works directly with Exchange instances.